# Compare polygons shape similarity with noise and different number of vertices

Tags: geometry, algorithms, polygons

Suppose that I have a reference polygon, $P_1$, and a test polygon, $P_2$. Both are defined by a certain number of ordered points:

$P_1$ = {$(x_1, y_1), (x2, y2)...(x_{n1}, y_{n1})$}

$P_2$ = {$(x_1, y_1), (x2, y2)...(x_{n2}, y_{n2})$}

$P_2$ is an approximation of $P_1$ and I want to compute the similarity between them. I [read](https://student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ecs763/Projects/phil.pdf) that I could compare their turn functions to do it. However, $P_2$ is very noisy and I am afraid that this solution would not work in this case. For example, I expect the following two polygons to result similar (the noise here is exaggerated). What could be the best approach?
[image]

Comment: May help: [Fréchet distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distance), [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance).

Comment: This is actually quite a profound question which likely invites more details to get to an answer.  In essence: What differences are small versus large?  For example:
- If two polygons are identical except for a “spike” that diverges a long way, does that mean they are equal?
- Are the polygons traversed at the same speed?

Comment: I am still not completely sure, but in my application small outliers (e.g. the spike you mentioned) should be ignored. What do you mean by "traversed at the same speed"?